# Ajax callback fails when method has parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm3.aspx/sayHello",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: AjaxSucceeded,
            error: AjaxFailed
        }); 
    });
    function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
        alert(result.d);
    }
    function AjaxFailed(result) {
        alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    }  
</script>
```

I have the following in my code behind.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string sayHello() 
{
    return "hello";
}
```

This works and shows hello.

Now, if I do:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string sayHello(string args) 
{
    return "hello";
}
```

Then I get internal server error 500 as a reply.

How can I change this to allow me to send actual data to the server side?

Comment: And you better enable debug mode. Error messages helps :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

This works:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "WebForm3.aspx/Test",
          data: '{"data":"abc"}',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (response) {
              alert(response.d);
          }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
data: {
    args: "hello world"
},
```

Also, remove both `contentType` and `dataType` as well.
Also, please add the `traditional: true`. Your resulting request will be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebForm3.aspx/sayHello",
    traditional: true,
    data: {
        args: "hello world"
    },
    success: AjaxSucceeded,
    error: AjaxFailed
});
```

Comment: @Milo Don't specify the `contentType` option too

Comment: @Milo Don't specify the `dataType` option either. That's saying "I expect the response to be in the format of JSON". In your case it isn't...it's "text/html" (normally the default that a web server uses) and the value is "hello world".

Comment: Removing that now the message is 'undefined'

Comment: And putting text/html gives me 200 OK